# SSRS ReportViewer Control. How to override print button?

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

After an SSRS report is rendered in a ReportViewer control, I need to determine if that report was actually sent to a printer. Is it possible? Is it possible to override print functionality of that control?

Answer (score 0):

You can't by default, but you can inject JavaScript to manipulate the DOM and thus change its behavior after it is rendered in the page.